# how to read all lines one by one from CSV and create multiple XML files accordingly(one file for one row) using shell scripts

Tags: bash, scripts, xml

I am trying to write a shell script to create multiple `.xml` files based on the data read from `.csv`. I need the help on how to make the loop for each `.xml` file creation.

#### Rough algorithm for this script

- set the in and out files in the script
- create any function or `do while` or `for` to read the each line from `.csv`
- create a `.xml` file with the name of emp-gid in any separate folder

#### Sample `Employee.csv`

```
23456,USD
89012,EUR
12345,CHF
34567,SGD
```

#### Sample `.xml` structure

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<fi:Organisation>
        <fi:Company>
                <fi:DEPARTMENT>Account</fi:DEPARTMENT>
                <fi:department-key>ABC123</fi:department-key>
                <fi:department-id>121</fi:department-id>
        </fi:Company>
        <fi:Employee>
                <fi:emp-gid>DE0008475021</fi:emp-gid>
                <fi:country>EUR</fi:country>
        </fi:body>
</fi:organisation>
```

#### My shell script

```
#!/bin/bash
InputFile="Employee.csv"
OutputFile="Emp_gid.xml"
echo '<?xml version="1.0"?>' > $OutputFile
echo '<fi:organisation>' >> $OutputFile
echo     '<fi:Company>' >> $OutputFile
echo         '<fi:DEPARTMENT>Account</fi:DEPARTMENT>' >> $OutputFile
echo         '<fi:department-key>ABC123</fi:department-key>' >> $OutputFile <-- want to increment by one for all xml file (ABC123,ABC124..) -->
echo         '<fi:department-id>121</fi:department-id>' >> $OutputFile <-- want to increment by one for all xml file (121,122,123,..) -->
echo     '</fi:Company>' >> $OutputFile
while IFS=$',' read -r -a arry
do
  echo       '  <fi:Employee>' >> $OutputFile
  echo          '    <fi:emp-gid>'${arry[0]}'</fi:emp-gid>' >> $OutputFile
  echo          '    <fi:country>'${arry[1]}'</fi:country>' >> $OutputFile
  echo      '  </fi:Employee>' >> $OutputFile
done < $InputFile
echo '</fi:organisation>' >> $OutputFile
```

This above script only generates one `.xml` file with all records. But I would like to expect some function or script which can generate separate `.xml` files for each row in the `.csv` file and put it into the separate folder.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this:

```
# a printf format string
xml_template=$(cat <<'XML'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<fi:Organisation>
        <fi:Company>
                <fi:DEPARTMENT>Account</fi:DEPARTMENT>
                <fi:department-key>%s%d</fi:department-key>
                <fi:department-id>%d</fi:department-id>
        </fi:Company>
        <fi:Employee>
                <fi:emp-gid>%s</fi:emp-gid>
                <fi:country>%s</fi:country>
        </fi:body>
</fi:organisation>    
XML
)

dept_key_prefix=ABC
dept_key=100         # choose suitable initial values
dept_id=100

while IFS=, read -r emp_gid country; do
    printf "$xml_template" \
            $dept_key_prefix \
            $((dept_key++)) \
            $((dept_id++)) \
            "$emp_gid" \
            "$country" \
        > "$emp_gid.xml"
done < Employee.csv
```

Comment: Thanks Glenn..Your script works. But when i tried to redirect to the generated xml to some other directory , the behavior is different and i could only see one xml is generated. Lets say i want to redirect the generated xml to this path "Xml_dir=/tmp/pos/xmldir". I declared this variable and used as follows ---$Xml_dir/"emp_gid.xml"--  in your script. But it doesn't work as expected. can you please correct what i missed.

Comment: you appear to have removed the `$` from the `$emp_gid` variable.

Comment: After added $ as suggested , it works fine. In addition, i am also planning to send these generated xml files to input of one of our another existing script. Like ourscript.sh <gid01.xml> and upon successful execution,this script continue to pick another xml. Would you suggest any logic/sample code to achieve this in your the above script? Thanks..